# cakephp2.0 Appcontroller function calling

Tags: cakephp-2.0

i have created one function in cakephp appcontrollet.php file. that retrive me the detail on that record from that id
the function is mentioned below

```
function getDetail($id = null)  // to check that user is valid or not 
  {
    $data = $this->ModelName->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('ModelName.is_active'=>'Y','ModelName.is_deleted'=>'N','ModelName.primaryKey'=>$id)));
    if($data !=array())
    {
      // return true;
      return $data;
    } else {
      $data = array();
      return $data;
      //return false;
    }
  }
```

Now i want to call this function from any controlller to get detail of the record like i will call this function fron Userscontroller,adminscontroller, marketscontroller etc. and it will return me the related data

my issue is that how should appcontroller know that request is come from which controller and which model to user ?

can anyone help me to solve this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Put this function to AppModel and call it from each controller with the related model. The function then looks like:

```
class AppModel extends Model
{
  public function getDetail($id = null) {
    $data = $this->find('all', array(
      'conditions' => array($this->name.'.id' => $id)
    ));

// ...
```

Depending on your call from the model it will automatically use the right model. Such a call may look like this:

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
  public $uses = array('User', 'Market');

  public function index()
  {
    // Fetch data from markets database
    $this->Market->getDetail($id);
    // Fetch data from users database
    $this->User->getDetail($id);

// ...
```

In this case, the model Market will be used to fetch the details from the database.

Comment: yep its working but how can i add condition like 'User.user_id'=>$id or 'Customer.customer_id'=>4 ..

Comment: In getDetails() you can use `$this->name` to get the name of the current model. Therefore the condition would be `$this->name.'.user_id' => $id`.

Comment: yes thats true suppose have called this function from UsersControlle then "$this->name.'.user_id' => $id" this works fine but what happened when this funnction called from another master like CustomersController or CompaniesController..

Comment: This is the same in other controllers. The variable `$this->name` depends on the call from the controller. `$this->User->getDetails()` will always fetch the data from users database. `$this->Market->getDetails()` will use the markets database. I edited my answer above to make this more clear.